# tr$A$=tr$AB$ Can you say anything about B?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products, trace, positive-semidefinite

How to prove that if
$tr{A}=tr(AB),$ then $B=I$ if A and B are positive semidefinite?

My attempt: $\langle A, I\rangle =\langle A, B\rangle=\langle A, I-B \rangle$.

I do not know where to start. I feel that if I knew that eigenvalues of $B$ are at most 1, then $I-B$ would have been positive semidefinite and so the inner product of positive semidefinite matrices is 0 iff one of the matirces is 0. But I do not have that...

From my problem it follows that $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, but I do not know anything about the eigenvalues of $B$. Is it necessary that $A,B\ge 0$ or is it enough that at least one of $A,B$ is psd?

Thank you!

Comment: Certainly not true without any additional assumptions. Take $A$ to be $diag(1,-1) $, i.e., the diagonal matrix with 1 and -1 on the diagonal. Take $B$ to be $diag(n,n)$ for some integer n. Then $tr(A) =0$ and $tr(AB) =0$.

Comment: Or just $A = B =0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Edited.

Comment: $0$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be positive definite, it's not true.  Try
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{t & 0\cr 0 & 2-t}$$
for $0 < t < 2$.

Comment: Oh, that's nice, thanks. Do you think there are any restrictions I can put on A that will make the statement true?

Comment: No, it's never true for $n \times n$ matrices with $n > 1$.  For any $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $A \ne 0$, $\text{tr}(A) > 0$.  Take any $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $C$ with $\text{tr}(AC) > 0$, and there will be $t \in (0,\infty)$ such that $B = t C$ works.